# PayPal express checkout for Mobile android

Tags: android, paypal, express-checkout

I am trying to implement MCEL in my application to be able to sell some digital goods.

previously I had MCL which is pretty easy to setup but MCEL is confusing me a little bit.

the example code which was given by paypal MECL is accessing some weburl based .jsp

If I want to use MCEL

1. do I need SSL server?, SSL website?
2. I have linux hosting with PHP. is it enough for MCEL?
3. Paypal says we need to pass this url from a secure server

   ```
   https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkoutmobile " +
       "&drt=" +_deviceReferenceToken + "&token=valueFromSetExpressCheckoutResponse";
   ```
4. I get the deviceReferenceId when I initialize the paypal instance but where do I get the ValueFromSetExpressCheckoutResponse?
5. Can anyone please show me some code how to begin with MCEL?

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to use ExpressCheckout API first:

Send a link like this:`"https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?METHOD=setExpressCheckout&VERSION=87.0&USER=xxx&PWD=xxxx&SIGNATURE=xxx&RETURNURL=http://www.google.com/&CANCELURL=http://www.mydomain.com/checkout/order/error&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Toggi+Calgary&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=TOGGICALGARY&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=Colour%3A+Black%2C+Size%3A+4%2 &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=58.60&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=58.60&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=30.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=14.65 &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=103.25"`

then you can get response:

```
TOKEN=EC%2d0TU74507629133059&TIMESTAMP=2012%2d10%2d14T03%3a58%3a24Z&CORRELATIONID=a6920fdc12539&ACK=Success&VERSION=87%2e0&BUILD=3893058
```

here is the token you need.If you don't have (&USER=xxx&PWD=xx&SIGNATURE=xx), you need to create a seller account on sandbox